# Algorithm question about assigning chores to children (ford-fulkerson)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

My problem is:

There is an input list of 5 children and a list of chores that they would prefer to complete.

Let days be equal to 10, and for each day, there are 2 chores that they must complete.

There are restraints where each child must complete at least 3 chores and at most 5 chores, each chore must only be completed by 1 child, and no child is allowed to complete both chores in a day.

My goal is to find an allocation where each child is allocated the chores where this allocation satisfies the restraints above.

I understand that I can create a bipartite graph with vertices u<sub>i</sub> corresponding to children, and v<sub>j</sub> corresponding to chores. Then, I can draw edges from vertices u<sub>i</sub> to v<sub>j</sub> corresponding to each child's preference to each chore. I understand these edges will have a capacity of one (as each chore can only be completed once). Furthermore, I know to add a start vertex, with an edge from each vertex u<sub>i</sub> to the start vertex, and also to add a sink vertex, with an edge from each vertex v<sub>j</sub> to the sink vertex.

However, I am confused about how to implement the restraint where each child must complete at least 3 chores and at most 5 chores. Where does this restraint fit on this bipartite graph?

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: "a list of chores that they would prefer to complete"  Prefer?  It seems to me that this would be a list of chores that the child CAN complete, since there either is or is not a link from child to chore.  The problem of modelling preferences and optimizing the total 'satisfaction' of all children is much harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a total of 20 tasks to complete (2 each day). Each child must complete 3 of those 20, and up to 5. That means that when each child has done his minimum of tasks, 5 remains to be done.

- Make the edge from the source to each child with a maximum capacity of 3.
- Make a vertice `rt` (remaining tasks"), with an edge from the source to `rt` with a capacity of 5, and some edge from `rt` to each child, with a capacity of 2 (each child can only complete 2 of the 5 remaining tasks)

With this setup, there is a total capacity of 20, so if all 20 tasks are completed, it is forced that each child do 3 of them.

Comment: How would I distinguish between each task if the graph is drawn this way? As in, how would I know if child 1 is doing chore 1 or child 2 is doing chore 3, etc? Is there a way to draw an equivalent graph showing all tasks and what each child's preference to each task is?

Comment: this does not modify the graph between children and tasks, only between source and children. Just use your bipartite graph for the rest.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now.  But I don't think I phrased my question correctly; how would I know which remaining task has been completed?

Comment: If there exist a solution, there will be 20 flow from child to tasks. Those will be the one completed. The "remaining" task is just a trick to enforce the 3 to 5 task per child, it bare no other meaning.